# Four dogs and five cats race. In how many ways can this occur?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Four dogs and five cats enter a race. The cats are clearly superior; they place first, second, and third. In how many ways can this happen?

My attempt: Since the cats come in the first three places and any of the $5$ cats can come in first, second, and third in any order, there would be $C(5,3)$ number of possibilities for the winning cats. Now there are $9-3 = 6$ animals left. They can come in $6!$ different places.

So would the answer be $C(5,3)*6!$. Or am I completely off and thinking about this wrong.

Comment: But of your first three cats, order matters also, right?  Combinations take into account choosing 3 different cats from 5 but not in order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the order of the first three cats matters, and so it would be a permutation as opposed to a combination. In other words, you want $P(5,3) = 60$ as opposed to $C(5,3) = 10$. Combinations have the characteristic that the order of whatever you are studying doesn't matter. Besides that minor problem, your thinking is pretty much spot on =)

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thank you for explaining; that makes a lot of sense.